# New class in OWL, which constraint should I use?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

Using property `:hasFilm` and class `:JamesCameronFilm` define the new class of people who have only James Cameron's films (they have only Cameron's films. They can't have other director's films). How the class should look? Should I use the `:allValuesFrom`, `:someValuesFrom` or another constraint?

```
:PeopleHaveFilms owl:equivalentClass [
  rdf:type owl:Restriction;
  owl:onProperty :hasFilm;
  owl:hasValue :JamesCameronFilm
] .
```

Is it correct?

`:PeopleHaveFilms` is the new class (the class of people who have only James Cameron's films, not the other director's films). I have the `:JamesCameronFilm` class and the property `:hasFilm`.

Comment: Please, improve your question. What have you tried? Where are you stuck at? Which OWL syntax are you using? What's the name of the property for expressing the "haveDirector" relation?

Comment: :PeopleHaveFilms  owl:equivalentClass
[rdf:type owl:Restriction;
owl:onProperty :hasFilm;
owl:hasValue :JamesCameronFilm
] .    I dont know which constraint should i use

Comment: neither of those axioms model constraints, that's just used for inference aka entailment. For constraints you need other languages, e.g. SHeX or SHACL.

Comment: I neither need SHeX nor SHACL. As u said I just need inference.

Comment: you never mentioned "inference" in your question, all you did was talking about "constraint" ...

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `owl:hasValue :JamesCameronFilm`, because `:JamesCameronFilm` is a class, not an individual.

You should instead use `owl:allValuesFrom :JamesCameronFilm` for stating that **all** the films seen by `:PeopleHaveFilms` must be of James Cameron:

```
:PeopleHaveFilms owl:equivalentClass [
  rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
  owl:allValuesFrom :JamesCameronFilm ;
  owl:onProperty :hasFilm
] .
```

If you also want to state that all the `:PeopleHaveFilms` *must* have seen at least one James Cameron's film, you can add a second restriction (specifying an `owl:minCardinality` constraint) using the intersection:

```
:PeopleHaveFilms owl:equivalentClass
  owl:intersectionOf (
    [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
      owl:allValuesFrom :JamesCameronFilm ;
      owl:onProperty :hasFilm
    ]
    [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
      owl:minCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
      owl:onProperty :hasFilm
    ]
  ) .
```

Comment: Using constraint :allValuesFrom there is a possibility that property :hasFilm doesn't exist. Am I right?

Comment: @sawwn Exactly. ∀x.Q(x) is true even if it doesn't exist any x such that Q(x).

Comment: So if there is no :hasFilm, :PeopleHaveFilms don't need to have any film especially :JamesCameronFilm @horcrux

Comment: @sawwn Yes, but in that case you have that all the people that have seen no films are :PeopleHaveFilms. If this is ok, then use the first rule; otherwise, if you want to avoid this, then use the second rule.

Comment: If I want to avoid having no films then I should pick the 2nd rule because in that second rule it must be at least one :JamesCameronFilm and not other director's films?

Comment: @sawwn Yes, exactly